# Vacuous Probabilities

Tags: probability, logic

Suppose it we have that for all $x \in X$, $\neg ( Ax \wedge Bx)$ holds.  Then can we say anything about the value of $P(Ax \mid Bx \wedge x \in X)$?

Can we say, for example, any of the following?

1. $P(Ax \mid Bx \wedge x \in X) = 0$
2. $P(Ax \mid Bx \wedge x \in X) = 1$, vacuously.
3. $P(Ax \mid Bx \wedge x \in X)$ is undefined.

Comment: If $P(Bx \wedge x \in X) \gt 0$ then the correct answer is the first

Comment: What if $P(Bx \wedge x \in X) = 0$?

Comment: @PP121 Then the conditional probability is undefined.